# How do I add word count to output message on successful write?

Tags: save

After I write a file with <kbd>:w!</kbd> I see in the ruler the following output message text in the ruler or status line:

```
"FILE_NAME" 192L, 9357C written
```

1. What is this output message text called in the `help` system?
2. How do I edit it to show word count?

The output of the `wc` command shows line, word and character counts.

```
wc ./FILE_NAME
192 1695 9357 ./FILE_NAME
```

When I write a file I would like to add **1695W** to the output message text shown.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, what that message is called like and did not find anything in the help currently. However what the message looks like can be influenced with the  ['shm'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shm%27) (shortmessage) option and the flag `l`, see link.

If you want to change it, I would suggest to create a [BufWritePost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufWritePost) autocommand, that outputs the required information, e.g. like this:

```
function! WordCount()
  let wc=wordcount()
  return  '"'.
    \ expand("<afile>"). '" '.
    \ line('$'). 'L, '.
    \ wc['chars']. 'C '.
    \ wc['words']. 'W written'
endfunction

augroup MyBufWritePost
  au!
  au BufWritePost * echom WordCount()
augroup END
```